# Are there any plans to simplify console service management on Ubuntu?

Tags: upstart, services, console, init.d

I am quite perplexed about the direction in which service management is going on Ubuntu and the funny part is that the same seems to be happening with OS X but that's another story.

I do appreciate simplicity and doing `service srv start|stop|restart` was nice and always displiked the fact the service cannot enable and disable services (even if these commands are not implemented by the called scripts).

To overcome this I was using `update-rc.d srv enable|disable` or even installing chkconfig to do the same.

Now with upstart things seems to go worse instead of better and I am wondering if anyone is working on fixing this, or the desire of

**What would be the easy way to manage the services?** (Ubuntu 12.04,14.04+)

Optional: Is there a bug/feature request for improving it?

Use case: As a (root) user I want to be able to easily perform these actions:
* start, stop, restart service
* enable/disable service
* list current services and their enabled/disabled state
* list current services and their running/stopped state
* (optional) have a simple bash-able way to check if a service is enabled/disabled, running or stopped.

PS. Don't say a thing about GUI tools, please.

Comment: «Now with upstart things seems to go worse instead of better»

This is vague and extremely subjective. "Better" and "worse" are a matter of opinion, so you should clarify what you think is better or not.

«PS. Don't say a thing about GUI tools, please.»

Precisely... There are people who prefer GUI tools and think they are better. This is just personal preference, there is no objective way to state one approach is "better".

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto quite happy to see that I am not the only one seeing the same problem. I guess for the same of implementing the next big thing some devs fail to see the power of simplicity and the importance of hiding the complexity. I don't give a **** if this is an old/new stype service, as an user I should be able to control all services using an easy interface. The irony is that here Microsoft made some good progress, they do have a pretty good command line utility for that.

Comment: A opinion based I answer I could to is that systemd used by other linux distros is better, as it simply works and requires no hassle. apparently [this is possible to use in Ubuntu](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-and-test-systemd-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/), and [will be](http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-16-04-will-be-using-systemd-instead-of-canonicals-upstart/).

Comment: Yes, `systemd` does do all that. So the question comes a bit too late. :D

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy way to start, stop, restart, reload services:

```
service srv start|stop|restart|reload
```

or

```
invoke-rc.d srv start|stop|restart|reload
```

or

```
initctl start|stop|restart|reload srv
```

or

```
start|stop|restart|reload srv
```

(service command is your best bet)

#### Easy way to enable/disable services:

```
update-rc.d srv enable|disable
```

(still works with Upstart)

#### Current services and their running/stopped state:

For all:

```
initctl list
```

For running:

```
initctl list | grep start/running
```

For stopped:

```
initctl list | grep stop/waiting
```

Unfortunately, services started with sysv scripts are not listed here, only Upstart jobs.

#### Missing:

Check enabled/disabled state of all services.

Check running or enabled state of specific service.